# union \ intersection of index

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a qusetion in my book without an answer and I wanted to know if I got it right:

In this question N is the universal group and for  every $  n \in N $we can denote An = { 0 , 1 , 2 ,3 , ....., n}

For the following 1~4 I need to decide if it eqaul to one of  groups a~d in the image below them :

1.N   , 2. N \ {0} , 3. $\emptyset$ , 4. none of them

the groups are :

[groups image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bxUt.jpg)

my results :

a = N (1)

b = $\emptyset$ (3)

c = not sure i got something weird like union of these elements: ( $\emptyset$ , 2 ,{3,4} , {6,5,4} , ...) so my answer was - none (4)

d = again not sure ,union of these elements  (1, 2 ,3 , ...) - so my answer was N{0} (4)

Comment: There are things unclear. What is meant by "group" ("set" maybe?), "universal group" ("set of natural numbers" maybe?), "belong to" ("is element of", or "is subset of" maybe?)?

Comment: What is that you got ('if I got it right')? I expected an attempt for a solution, or at least, a guess.

Comment: univeral group mean that U = N . so all of the groups in the world are sub groups of N . this is part of the question as it written in my book and I only translated it , maybe my translation is wrong .
I will fix the belong to - my bad.

about the solution well I thought that writing my way might be to long and to unclear and I wanted to know what is the 'cleanest' way or easiest way to understand and to solve these kind of questions . 
I'll add my final solution tho